# Why it enters 'replace mode' automatically even with '--clean' flag in WSL?

Tags: vim-windows

To demonstrate the whole reproducing process, I make a video:
https://youtu.be/UD38-wnwGnw

As you can see, I enter my vim with '--clean' flag.
No vimrc, no plugins, but it still enter the 'replace mode' automatically.
It is so annoying, anyone knows what's going on?

---

Update:
After entered clean vim(with --clean flag, but issue remained), I checked if any unexpected scripts had been executed:
[image: Seems nothing special]
Seems nothing special, everything belongs to official content.

And I also checked my 'vi' command, confirmed that where it comes from:
[image: Nothing special neither]
Nothing special neither, too.

I still have no idea toward this issue.

Comment: Since it's loaded with `--clean` you might want to check your defaults.vim file to make sure it hasn't been modified. Also, make sure `vi` is properly aliased to `vim`: `type -a vi`.

Comment: And `:verbose set ...` can help find where an option was set (e.g., `verbose set insertmode?`)

Comment: You can also confirm which scripts are executed at startup with `:scriptnames`. But yeah, I think `:verbose set insertmode?` is what should give it away... If you figure out what's causing it and know the answer, please post it as an answer! If you still can't explain it, please [edit] the question to include the additional information you gathered.

Comment: Also, welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Thanks, pals.
I posted some further testing information, but nothing changed.

Comment: Check the `:verbose set insertmode?` too though!

Comment: Do you have environment variables such as `VIMINIT` or `EXINIT` set? Try `echo $VIMINIT` (and `echo $EXINIT`) in your shell...

Comment: @filbranden Do you want me to verbose the `insertmode` state AFTER cancel the replace mode and focus to command bar? Of course, it shows 'noinsertmode'.

Comment: @filbranden I have no environment variables such as `VIMINIT` or `EXINIT`, though I don't know what they means.

Comment: Any chance any of the `*.vim` scripts being loaded has a `startinsert` command in it?

Comment: `:startreplace` actually...

Comment: In the future, [Please don't post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)

Answer (score 3):

That is a known issue: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/6951 and https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/6365

As a temporary fix, add `set t_u7=` to your vimrc.

PS, the issue was introduced by windows terminal and is fixed there.

Comment: Windows Terminal Bug report: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/1637 there is no released fixed binary version available yet, although the issue has been fixed in the source.